# Counter example to Lipschitz contraction in compact metric space

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

> Let $E$ be a compact metric space and let $f:E\rightarrow E$   be such that
>   $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ when $x\neq y$.  Prove or give a counter example
>   to the following statement:
>
> There exists $0\leq \alpha <1$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))<\alpha d(x,y)$
>   for all $x,y\in E$

I think this is false and gave the following counter example:

$f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x & ,0<x<1\\
\frac{1}{2} & ,x=1\lor x=0
\end{cases}$

My intuition is that in this mapping the distance can be arbitrarily close to 1 but never 1 and hence there's no such $\alpha$. 
Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I am afraid it is not correct. The property $d(f(x), f(y))<d(x, y)$ implies that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counter-example is not correct: $f$ should be a continuous function with respect to the distance $d$ (see Giuseppe Negro's comment).

Take $E=[0,1]$ with the euclidean distance $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $f(x)=\arctan(x)$. Then $f:E\to E$ and if $x,y\in [0,1]$ with $x\not=y$, by the Mean Value Theorem, there is $t\in (0,1)$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(t)||x-y|=\frac{1}{1+t^2}|x-y|<|x-y|.$$
Is there $\alpha \in [0,1)$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\alpha |x-y|$
for all $x,y\in [0,1]$?

Comment: I don't understand your point when you use the Mean Value Theorem. As I can understand no such $\alpha$ exists since the derivative of $\arctan(x)$ takes the value 1 at $x=0$.